# Page jumps after AJAX Call to PHP chat

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

So, when i press the "send button" the page jumps up to the top which should happen. Any ideas? I've tried animating and return false but nothing seems to work. JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/xwyzs05v/2/

AJAX:

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'chat.php',
        success: function(data){

          $('#messages').html(data);
        }
      });
  },1000);

});

$('#formInput').submit(function(){

    var message = $('#message').val();
    var sender = $('#sender').val();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'send.php',
      data: { sender: sender, message: message },
      success: function(data){

      }
    $('#message').val('');
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I'm prepared to put the same amount of effort into helping you, as you did in creating that fiddle to help us, help you.

Comment: Hi, i'm sorry for that @Lee. I've updated the JsFIDDLE for easier readability. I'm sitting without a texteditor right now as i'm coding through a CMS system online and updating the changes through that, (hence the crappy text-indentation).

Comment: do you mean that the page shouldn't 'jump'? and if so have you tried using a button element outside the `<form>` to handle the ajax trigger?

Comment: You realize you could change `<input type="submit"` to `<input type="button"` and that would fix it, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error because you write `$("#message").val("")` out of a success function.

Correct code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#formInput').submit(function(){

    var message = $('#message').val();
    var sender = $('#sender').val();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'send.php',
      data: { sender: sender, message: message },
      success: function(data){
            $('#message').val('');
      }

    });

    return false;
});


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of submitting form, you could just catch a click event on form submit button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit-button').click(function(e){

var message = $('#message').val();
var sender = $('#sender').val();

$.ajax({
  url: 'send.php',
  data: { sender: sender, message: message },
  success: function(data){

  }
  $('#message').val('');
});

return false;
});
});
```